# Difference Between Castle Windsor LifeStyle Configurations

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

What's the difference between these two?

```
Component.For<IMyType>()
    .LifeStyle
    .PerWebRequest
    .UsingFactoryMethod(() => new MyType());
```

and

```
Component.For<IMyType>()
     .UsingFactoryMethod(() => new MyType())
     .LifeStyle
     .Is(LifestyleType.PerWebRequest);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the same. The only difference is that the API has been simplified (made less verbose, more direct). You can simplify it even further with Windsor 3:

```
Component.For<IMyType>()
    .LifestylePerWebRequest()
    .UsingFactoryMethod(() => new MyType());
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also the first one is "hardcoding" the lifestyle whereas the latter might be used when the lifestyle is provided from _outside_